# Optimizing SQL Query: One-to-one relationship but structured like one-to-many

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a table structure that looks something like this:

**Person**

```
Id
```

**PersonDemographic**

```
Id  
PersonId
```

The `Person > PersonDemographic` is a one to one relationship and is forced to be so via a unique constraint on `PersonDemogrphic.PersonId`.

This structure pervades this particular database.  As a result, any join from Person to the tables containing person details comprises hash matches and table scans.

In an effort to optimize the query, I tried making person ids (rather than the table identities) the clustered primary key.  This resulted in nested loops and Clustered Index Scans (and a slight performance improvement).

Knowing that it's a one-to-one relationship I thought I might be able to improve performance by giving the join the `FORCESEEK` hint; however, that made it worse.  Based on the statistics in the execution plan, it appears the clustered index seek on the "reversed relationship" tables is still executing the operator once per row as opposed to the execution for the "usually related" tables which has an estimated number of executions of 1.

I'm looking for suggestions to get the optimal execution plan for this scenario.  While I realize *"fix your table structure"* is valid and is probably the best answer, I'm hoping to avoid that at this time.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what are the primary/foreign keys and indexes? A lot of optimization can be done with the indexes.

Comment: Can you show the execution plan of the query and an example of your query?

Comment: I can try to compose a sample, but to show the actual plan would require an act of congress (literally).  I can also try to describe it better.  The general concept I'm dealing with is the reversed nature of the one-to-one relationship.  I think the optimizer sees this table structure and thinks, "oh, that's one to many . . . I need to look for every row that matches" when I know there's only one row that matches and I want it to stop looking when it finds it.

Comment: Then you can add a unique non clustered index to the table wich will let SQL know that it is unique.

Comment: Isn't a primary key unique by definition?

Comment: If you have a unique index on the same key on both and an FK then that is a `1 to 0-1` relationship. Please show your queries and execution plans.

Comment: I'm building a demo now.  In my environment, I don't have permission to create tables so it'll be a minute. :-/  Sorry.

Comment: Yes, but since you say that SQL seems to think it's a one to many relationship, then maybe the primary key is not well structured for your query. Without seeing an example of the tables, keys, queries and execution plan, it's hard to help, I can only guess based on what you are saying.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to reproduce the results I'm getting in my development environment.  It appears the execution plans are identical when there are few data in the tables.  I'm populating the tables with sample data and will do more testing.  I'll post my demo when I get it performing appropriately undesirably. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a foreign key instead of just an unique constraint?

Comment: It was a foreign key with a unique constraint.  The foreign key wouldn't enforce uniqueness anyhow based on the "reversedness" (neologism of the day) of the relationship; however, I have tried making the PersonId foreign key also be the Primary Key of the table thus enforcing uniqueness.